# What is a word meaning bounce back?

Tags: meaning, nouns

Just want a good word to use. :) I feel as if bounce back isn't really that..sophisticated, I guess of a word. Thanks!

Comment: You can look for its synonyms. Recoup, recuperate, convalesce...

Comment: I you don't want a "re" word, you can say somthing like "get back on course", or "get back to form" or "get back to par"

Comment: "back on an even keel", or "off the bench/back in the game"

Comment: Ricochet, recoil, backfire, and the ever unsophisticated "return".

Answer (score 5):

**Rebound**

> [Definition of rebound](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebound)
>   intransitive verb
>
> 1
>   a :  to spring back on or as if on collision or impact with another body
>
> b :  to recover from setback or frustration
>   ....

Answer (score 0):

How about [ricochet](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ricochet)?

"A rebound or skipping, as of a ball along the ground when a gun is fired at a low angle of elevation, or of a fiat stone thrown along the surface of water."

Sounds sophisticated enough to me lol